# SQLAlchemy query results directly to numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

So I've been capturing push updates from a site for a couple of weeks now. I intend to do some analyses on it - least squares first, then maybe some clustering, NN, etc. - so I want it in a matrix not an array.

However, I am looking for the fastest way to dump tens of thousands of rows into a numpy matrix for processing. For example, my test of a single day is yielding over 16,000 rows. Currently these are being processed like such:

```
        for upd in api_updates:
            times.append(upd.Update_Time)
            data = np.vstack([data, upd.data_vector])
```

The `upd` object is a row returned from SQLAlchemy (the tables are defined using declarative_base). The data_vector attribute is one I've added where the table fields are put into an np.matrix as a single row.

Obviously, adding each row, 1 at a time, to the matrix `data` is very slow.

Is there a way to add these rows in bulk? Or is it faster to do some form of pre-initialization and then update - via loop - each element in the final matrix?

TIA

Comment: The basic approach is collect the values in a list (list append is fast), and create the array once, at the end.  That's true regardless of the source of the sublists.  If you know the final size, creating a `empty` array, and inserting values by row index also works.

Comment: What's the nature of `upd.data_vector`?

Comment: `upd` is a declarative_base object representing a row from the DB. The `data_vector` of the upd object attribute is simply the relevant table fields cast to float and put in an np.matrix (row vector) for concatenation with the already existing `data` matrix.

Comment: So would the proper approach be to change data_vector to a list of values. Then append that list to data like such: `data.append(upd.data_vector)`? Then cast to an np.matrix object?

Comment: I don't think it matters alot whether you collect a list lists or a list of arrays.  I'd have to run timetests on a sample case to argue for one over the other.

Comment: I have not test the list of arrays. However, here is the improvement using a list of lists:
Original - 6.5 sec
List of lists - 4.0 sec
on 16,400+ rows